# SharePoint Patching - Configuration database version: mismatch

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, patching

I installed SharePoint 2013 Feb 2020 CU on one of my farms but the Configuration database version:
15.0.5207.1000 which is Jan 2020 CU.

It was a clean installation and I didn't get any errors during installation or running PSConfig.

Answer (score 0):

Have you received any error message when using SharePoint? Do you see any content database in status of *Upgrade Available* via `Central Administration > Upgrade and Migration > Review database status`?

If yes, run [psconfig.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/upgrade-available-status-in-new-farm) to do an upgrade

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources
```

If not, check the blog of Stefan Goßner below, which might give you a hint of the situation:

[SharePoint does not have a build version. Full Stop.](https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2016/08/23/sharepoint-does-not-have-a-build-version-full-stop/)